# How to force prebuild script to run at each compile

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

We currently use Delphi 2009 and GIT to develop an application. We have set up a prebuild script to generate a version number and build ID using information from git and compile this as a resource that is included in the project. The problem is that this script doesn't run on a regular compile. This means that the other developers can end up with a discrepancy between the actual version number and the number in the resource (especially when switching branches in git).

Since we use our software to make some critical calculations, we would like to use this build id to reproduce calculations and track down problems.

Other than trying to force my developers to frequently press shift-F9, how can I ensure that the the prebuild script gets run when necessary (ideally at each compile)?

Jason

UPDATE: It's true that the pre-build script gets run at each compile. The problem was that I expected to get a different result pressing F9 after making a tag in git, even though no code had changed.

Comment: my pre build actions run every compile. I can't imagine why yours don't.

Comment: Well, when I compile/run the program by pressing F9, the version information is often out of date. Shift-F9 always fixes this. I suppose I could be more rigorous, but it's probably also reasonable to assume that a prebuild batch is just that.. preBUILD, and thus only is started when explicitly building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre build actions do run before every compile.

You state in a comment that the actions sometimes don't run when you press F9. That makes sense because F9, or Run, only invokes a compile if source is deemed to have changed.

A BeforeCompile notifier plug in will behave in exactly the same way. Your solution is to make sure that you compile before running using Ctrl+F9.

Answer (score 3):

We solved a similar issue by writing a custom IDE plugin which uses the IOTAIDENotifier50 interface. Specifically using the BeforeCompile method, to test some required project settings and also generate dynamic version information (VERSIONINFO resource). It gets called for every type of build (compile and build). We also generate a unique exe serial number and log everything, which helps us track down issues and is similar to your script. For completeness we have only done this in Delphi 2007 and Delphi XE.

Comment: That sounds like something that I don't have the resources (time) to do myself. Would you be willing to share some source code from your plugin?

Comment: although it wouldn't solve your problem, writing such an add in is trivially easy. Before pre and post build actions were added I did exactly the same as Steve and it really is simple.